# form without action using onsubmit="return ValidateRegitration();"

Tags: javascript, php

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<base href="http://www.supervan.in/">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/show_basket_data.js?1410616290"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="modelbox/reveal.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="modelbox/jquery.reveal.js"></script>
<script>
function removemessage(val,acton){
    if(val=="Hi! What can we find for you ?"){
        if(acton=='footer'){
        document.getElementById('searchstore').value="";
        }else{
        document.getElementById('search_store').value="";
        }
    }
}
function setmessage(val,acton){
    if(val==""){
        if(acton=='footer'){
        document.getElementById('searchstore').value="Search Supervan for product, category or brand";
        }else{
        document.getElementById('search_store').value="Search Supervan for product, category or brand";
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wizardDiv" align="center">
            <form action="" method="post" id="frmregisstration" name="frmregisstration" onsubmit="return ValidateRegitration();">
                <table width="100%" border="0">
                    <tbody><tr>
                        <td colspan="2" align="center"><div id="ShowError" style="color:#ED2024;height:40px; font-weight:bold;font-size:12px;"></div></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right"><input type="text" name="regfirstname" id="regfirstname" value="" size="14" class="textboxlarge" placeholder="First name"></td>
                        <td align="left"><input type="text" name="reglastname" id="reglastname" value="" size="14" class="textboxlarge" placeholder="Last name"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td colspan="2"> <input type="text" name="regemail" id="regemail" size="38" class="textboxlarge" value="" placeholder="Email for receipts"> </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"><input type="password" name="regpassword" id="regpassword" value="" size="38" class="textboxlarge" placeholder="Password"></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"><input type="password" name="regconfirmpassword" id="regconfirmpassword" value="" size="38" class="textboxlarge" placeholder="Re-enter password"></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="reg_contact_no" id="reg_contact_no" value="" size="38" onkeypress="return CheckNumericKeyInfo(event.keyCode, event.which,this.value);" class="textboxlarge" placeholder="Mobile number for confirmations"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" align="center"><div style="width:250px;text-align:left;margin-left:6px;">We only sell groceries, not your details.<br>Thanks for keeping us busy.</div></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" align="center"><div style="width:380px;text-align:left;margin-left:2px;"><input type="button" class="wiz_btn_inactive" value="« Back" onclick="window.history.back();"><input type="submit" class="l-btn" value="Next »" style="float:right;"></div></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table>
                <input type="hidden" name="browser_detail" id="browser_detail" value="Chrome 37.0.2062.120">
            </form>
            <br>
        </div>
<script>        
    function ValidateRegitration()
    {
        var emailexp=/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,8})+$/;
        var REG = /^[1-9]\d+$/;
        if(document.getElementById('regfirstname').value=="")
        {
            alert("Please Enter the First Name.");
            document.getElementById('regfirstname').focus();
            return false;
        }
        if(document.getElementById('reglastname').value=="")
        {
            alert("Please Enter the Last Name.");
            document.getElementById('reglastname').focus();
            return false;
        }
        if(document.getElementById("regemail").value=="" || (document.getElementById('regemail').value.search(emailexp)==-1)){
            alert("Please enter valid E-mail ID.");
            document.getElementById("regemail").focus();
            return false;
         }
         if(document.getElementById('regpassword').value=="")
         {
            alert("Please Enter Password");
            document.getElementById('regpassword').focus();
            return false;
        }
        if(document.getElementById('regpassword').value.length<5)
         {
            alert("Please Enters Minimum 5 Digits Password .");
            document.getElementById('regpassword').focus();
            return false;
        }
         if(document.getElementById('regconfirmpassword').value=="")
         {
            alert("Please Enter Re-Password");
            document.getElementById('regconfirmpassword').focus();
            return false;
        }
        if((document.getElementById('regconfirmpassword').value!="") && (document.getElementById('regpassword').value!=document.getElementById('regconfirmpassword').value))
        {
            alert("Confirm Password's do not match.");
            document.getElementById('regconfirmpassword').focus();
            return false;
        }



        if(document.getElementById('reg_contact_no').value==""){
            alert("Please Enter The Registered Contact No.");
            document.getElementById('reg_contact_no').focus();
            return false;
        }
        if((document.getElementById('reg_contact_no').value.search(REG)==-1) || (document.getElementById('reg_contact_no').value.length<10))
        {
            alert("Please Enter Valid 10 Digits of Registered Contact No.");
            document.getElementById('reg_contact_no').focus();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    } 
</script>       
</body> 
</html>
```

I was doing a research on forms , I found a form which has no action in view source . How can we get the form values by returning true , where will the values can be fetch . i am trying to search how it can be done but i didn't find my answer  so please help me

Comment: The function `ValidateRegitration();` simply returns true and allows the page to post to its self in the event that the registration is OK (returns true). Otherwise, it shows the errors on the page before the page is submit (client side validation). If it returns true, then the form data is posted to the same page that you're on` registration.php` which likely contans `if(isset($_POST['elementNames']))` and such, then performs a `header('Location: home.php');` if everything goes OK.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a small script for you. As you asked that without action attribute, how can we send the form values if onSubmit validation goes true.
So, We can do this thing in 2 ways,

- Through Javascript Hidden type
- Through AJAX call.

I have written code using javascript hidden type:

```
<?php
if($_POST['hid'] == "true")
{
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 echo "Posted Value : ".$name;
 unset($_POST);
 echo "Posted Value is unset".$_POST['name'];
}
?>

<html>
<head>
<script>
function validate()
{ 
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var hid = document.getElementById("hid").value;
  if(name != '')
  {
    document.getElementById("hid").value = "true";
    console.log("true");
    return true;
  }
  console.log("false");
  return false;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="" onSubmit="return validate()">
<input id="name" name="name" type="text">
<input id="hid" name="hid" type="hidden" value="false">
<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here in this code,
I have created **hidden type variable** whose by **default value is false**. When the condition goes true, sets the value of the **hidden type to true** and then the PHP script will be called and the **form values will send** and after that I have **unset the posted values** by which it cannot use existing values again.

I hope it

Answer (score -1):

Script hack fb...

```
<form method="post" action="/recover/password?u=100007702657756&amp;n=542903" onsubmit="return window.Event &amp;&amp; Event.__inlineSubmit &amp;&amp; Event.__inlineSubmit(this,event)" id="u_0_3">
   <input type="hidden" name="lsd" value="AVpICGr3" autocomplete="off">
   <div class="mvl ptm uiInterstitial uiInterstitialLarge uiBoxWhite">
      <div class="uiHeader uiHeaderBottomBorder mhl mts uiHeaderPage interstitialHeader">
         <div class="clearfix uiHeaderTop">
            <div class="rfloat _ohf">
               <h2 class="accessible_elem">Choose a new password</h2>
               <div class="uiHeaderActions"></div>
            </div>
            <div>
               <h2 class="uiHeaderTitle" aria-hidden="true">Choose a new password</h2>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="phl ptm uiInterstitialContent">
         <div class="mvm uiP fsm">A strong password is a combination of letters and punctuation marks. It must be at least 6 characters long.</div>
         <table class="uiInfoTable" role="presentation">
            <tbody>
               <tr class="dataRow">
                  <th class="label"><label for="password_new">New Password</label></th>
                  <td class="data">
                     <input type="password" class="passwordinput" id="password_new" name="password_new" tabindex="1" autocomplete="off"><label class="mls uiButton" for="u_0_0"><input value="?" onclick="show_pwd_help(); return false;" tabindex="3" type="button" id="u_0_0"></label>
                     <div id="password_new_status"></div>
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr class="dataRow">
                  <th class="label"><label for="password_confirm">Confirm Password</label></th>
                  <td class="data">
                     <input type="password" class="passwordinput" id="password_confirm" name="password_confirm" tabindex="2" autocomplete="off">
                     <div id="password_confirm_status"></div>
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
         <div class="mvl">
            <div class="uiInputLabel clearfix"><label class="_kv1 _55sg uiInputLabelInput"><input type="checkbox" name="reason" value="kill_sessions" id="u_0_1"><span></span></label><label for="u_0_1" class="uiInputLabelLabel">Log me out of Facebook everywhere else my account might be open. (Choose this if a stranger used your account.)</label></div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="uiInterstitialBar uiBoxGray topborder">
         <div class="clearfix">
            <div class="rfloat _ohf"><label class="uiButton uiButtonConfirm" id="btn_continue" for="u_0_2"><input value="Continue" name="btn_continue" type="submit" id="u_0_2"></label><a class="uiButton" href="/" role="button" name="reset_action"><span class="uiButtonText">Cancel</span></a></div>
            <div class="pts"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```